# Text expansion on click jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin I saw a long time ago that allowed to make text clickable that expands to something longer once clicked, the demo page had some sort of narration, and every part of the sentences was clickable to reveal more details. The demo page was minimalist, empty besides the black text on white background.

Features :

- makes any part of a paragraph clickable (invisible, it doesn't turn it into an underlined hyperlink) and attaches a longer description to it, most likely in an HTML `data-*` attribute
- on click, it expands the text (most likely with an animation but I can't remember it exactly) into the longer description specified before

Unfortunately I don't remember anything else, so before reimplementing it myself I'd like someone to find it if possible.

Comment: is it [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau not even close, the one I was talking about was seamless (no sign of clickable element nor "..." ellipsis) and the site was minimalist. Thanks anyway.